# Rails - Validate on Create Only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get my custom validation to work on `create`. But when I do a `find` then `save`, rails treats it as `create` and runs the custom validation. How do I get the validations to only work when creating a new record on not on the update of a found record?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Try this on your line of validation code:

```
validate :custom_validation, on: :create
```

this specifies to only run the validation on the `create` action.

Source:

[ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validate @ apidock.com](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.1.3.1/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validate)

Comment: Works on Rails 5.0.0.1 as well.

Answer (score 9):

#### TL;DR; Full example:

```
class MyPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :age_requirement


  private

  def age_requirement
    unless self.age > 21 
      errors.add(:age, "must be at least 10 characters in length")
    end
  end

end
```

To have the validator run only if a new object is being created, you can change the 2nd line of the example to: `validate :age_requirement, on: :create`

Only on updates: `validate :age_requirement, on: :update`

Hope that helps the next person!